# Sharing variables between threads in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I need to communicate with robot via sockets (this part works) and I'd like to make a watchdog to monitor if the robot is ready or not.

The communication handling is in while loop until the robot ends it. My thought was to use a bool variable whose value is inverted every time a valid message from robot is received.

In a separate thread also in a while loop the bool variable would be periodically checked against another bool with value from previous cycle to detect a change - a new command. When a change occurs, it should set watchdog state as ready. After some time without a command the watchdog is set to inactive.

The problem is that even when I see a new command received, the watchdog is still inactive (the output is almost always "-"). I tried to use mutex to eliminate problems in accessing variables from different threads but I might got it wrong - it didn't seem to help. Could you please give me a hint where the problem(s) might be?

The whole code is here:

```
#include<io.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

const ULONGLONG wdMaxTime = 10000;
bool wdAlive = false; // Robot ready? true = ready
bool wdState = false; // Changing value after a command is received
bool wdStateShadow = false; // Last value of wdState
std::mutex mtx;

DWORD WINAPI myThreadWatchdog()
{
    ULONGLONG start = GetTickCount64();
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        mtx.lock();
                // This should be executed every time a command is received..
                // ...but it's not
        if (wdState != wdStateShadow)
        {
            wdAlive = true;
            start = GetTickCount64();
            wdStateShadow = wdState;
        }

                // Too long without a command, watchdog is inactive
        if (GetTickCount64() - start > wdMaxTime) wdAlive = false;
                // Debug output
        if (wdAlive) printf("+");
        else printf("-");
        mtx.unlock();
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;
    size_t d;
    char message_received[128];

    std::thread worker_threadA(myThreadWatchdog);

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.167", &server.sin_addr);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(9999);

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    listen(s, 3);

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    do
    {
        new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c);
        if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        memset(message_received, 0, sizeof(message_received));
        d = recv(new_socket, message_received, sizeof(message_received) - 1, 0);
                // Now we have a command, let's handle it
        printf("Received: %s\n", message_received);
        const char* message;
        if (strncmp(message_received, "DATA", sizeof(message_received)) == 0)
        {
            message = "Data sent.";
            send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
        }
                // Flip the bool value for watchdog thread to notice
        mtx.lock();
        wdState = !wdState;
        mtx.unlock();
    } while (strncmp(message_received, "END", sizeof(message_received)) != 0);

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for reasons this isn't a grand idea, think no further than detecting commands in *pairs* with both received within the minimal sleep period of your watchdog, with long periods of idle *longer* than your sleep period between pair sets received. You will double-toggle your 'flag' and never know it it happened.

Comment: Sir, you are right about the problem. The idea was to send the commands from robot about every 10 seconds (non critical tasks) but the actual time was way shorter (less than a second) and I didn't realize that the reason of this problem happening might be in robot. Thank you kindly for your help. Might I ask one more thing - if I use the mutex correctly?